# How many of all cube's edges 3-colorings have exactly 4 edges for each color?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I've found the number of different cube's edges  colorings with three colors available.
 (We say that the two colorings are the same if one can obtain a second by turning cube and permuting colors)
My resualts credit are given to the following solution :

[Edge coloring of the cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150016/edge-coloring-of-the-cube) .

[solution summery : First of all define a group G, a set X and group action of G on X. We want to find the number of different cube edges coloring while we know that if we can obtain some coloring by turning another one – it is the same coloring. So we actually need to find the number of orbits of X (the orbit of an element x in X is the set of elements of X to which x can be moved by the elements of G) and then use Burnside's lemma . ]

So,  Now I want calculate how many of the 3-colorings I found have exactly 4 edges for each color ?

- this question asked in Combinatorics course as a bonus question.

Thanks! 
Bar

Comment: What book do you use in your course, out of curiosity

Comment: We don't have official book

Comment: FYI , This question was taken from home final-work in our course and I want to add solution to it,as a bonus. 
I just want  some help to find out what the tool which I should  use or even a simpler hint.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we construct the generating function of the edge colorings before the symmetric group acts on the colors. This requires the cycle index of the edge permutation group $E$ of the cube. We enumerate the permutations in this group by their cycle structure.

First, there is the identity, which contributes $$a_1^{12}.$$

There are rotations about an axis (three of them) passing through the center of two opposite faces, which gives $$3\times (a_2^6 + 2 a_4^3).$$

Rotations about a diagonal passing through opposite vertices give
$$4\times 2 a_3^4.$$

Finally there are 180 degree rotations about an axis passing through the centers of opposite edges, which gives $$6\times a_1^2 a_2^5.$$

This gives the cycle index
$$Z(E) = \frac{1}{24}
\left(a_1^{12} + 3 a_2^6 + 6 a_4^3 + 8 a_3^4 + 6 a_1^2 a_2^5\right).$$

Substituting into $Z(E)$ we obtain the following formula for the number of $N$-colorings of the edges of a cube the value
$$\frac{1}{24}(N^{12} + 3 N^6 + 6 N^3 + 8 N^4 + 6 N^7).$$
This gives the following sequence
$$1, 218, 22815, 703760, 10194250, 90775566, 576941778, 2863870080, 11769161895,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A060530](http://oeis.org/A060530).

The substituted cycle index for 3-colorings as asked for by the OP is
$$Z(E)(R+G+B)=
1/24\, \left( R+G+B \right) ^{12}+1/8\, \left( {R}^{2}+{G}^{2}+{B}^{2}
 \right) ^{6}\\+1/4\, \left( {R}^{4}+{G}^{4}+{B}^{4} \right) ^{3}+1/3\, \left(
{R}^{3}+{G}^{3}+{B}^{3} \right) ^{4}+1/4\, \left( R+G+B \right) ^{2} \left( {
R}^{2}+{G}^{2}+{B}^{2} \right) ^{5}$$
which yields
$$[R^4 G^4 B^4]Z(E)(R+G+B)=1479.$$

**Addendum** as of **Tue Dec 17 22:50:41 CET 2013.** The OP also mentioned in his query that as an extra twist we may consider edge colorings of the cube where the symmetric group acts on the colors, so that two colorings are not only equivalent when there is a rotation that transforms one into the other, but also a rotation combined with a permutation of the colors from the symmetric group. The technique for this kind of problem is called **Power Group Enumeration Theorem.**

There are at least two possible approaches here. There is the classic approach from the book *Graphical Enumeration* by Frank Harary and Edgar Palmer, a landmark text that continues to be relevant today. They have a chapter on this namely chapter six, section four "Power Group Enumeration / Graphs with colored lines." I will not typeset their formulas here as I would not add anything new and the text is available at any major library. Let me just say that they treat the following scenario: enumerate under the power group the colorings of various graphs, where an edge maybe on or off and has $N$ possible colors in the on state. I implemented their formula in Maple and the result was the following sequence for edge colorings of the cube under the symmetric group acting on the colors using at most $N$ colors:
$$1, 114, 3891, 29854, 87981, 143797, 170335, 177160, 178153, 178243,\ldots$$
This is the Maple code for the Harary/Palmer computation.

```
with(numtheory);
with(group):
with(combinat):


pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;



pet_varinto_power :=
proc(N, ZA)
           local beta, res, indvars, v, t, d, m, pot, ZB;

           ZB := pet_cycleind_symm(N);
           if N=1 then ZB := [ZB]; fi;

           indvars := indets(ZA);

           res := 0;
           for beta in ZB do
               t := [];
               for v in indvars do
                   pot := op(1, v);

                   m := 0;
                   for d in divisors(pot) do
                       m := m +
                       d*degree(beta, op(0,v)[d]);
                   od;

                   t := [op(t), v=1+m*z^pot];
               od;

               res := res+lcoeff(beta)*subs(t, ZA);
           od;

           res;
end;

cube_edge_ind :=
1/24*(a[1]^12+3*a[2]^6+6*a[4]^3+8*a[3]^4+6*a[1]^2*a[2]^5);


vgf :=
proc(N)
         option remember;
         local gf;

         gf := pet_varinto_power(N, cube_edge_ind);
         expand(gf);
end;

v := N -> coeff(vgf(N), z, 12);
```

The second approach uses a different Power Group Enumeration (PGET) formula as presented by Harald Fripertinger in his brilliant paper "Enumeration in Musical Theory" from 1993. Again I will not typeset the formulas here as I would not be adding anything new. The clinch is that this paper presents a so-called polynomial form of the PGET (in the first chapter) which makes it possible not only to calculate the total number of colorings but also to classify them according to the distribution of colors used. I have implemented this in Maple and I obtain for the sequence of colorings once more the values (that is as it ought to be):
$$1, 114, 3891, 29854, 87981, 143797, 170335,\ldots$$
Now, however, we also get the distributions of colors. For two colors we have
$$29\,{\it Q6\_Q6}+{\it Q12}+5\,{\it Q2\_Q10}+27\,{\it Q4\_Q8}+{\it Q1\_Q11}+13\,{\it
Q3\_Q9}+38\,{\it Q5\_Q7}  $$
and for three colors
$$ {\it Q12}+38\,{\it Q5\_Q7}+27\,{\it Q4\_Q8}+{\it Q1\_Q11}+5\,{\it Q2\_Q10}+13\,{\it
Q3\_Q9}+370\,{\it Q2\_Q5\_Q5}\\+29\,{\it Q6\_Q6}+600\,{\it Q2\_Q4\_Q6}+236\,{\it
Q1\_Q5\_Q6}+85\,{\it Q1\_Q3\_Q8}+77\,{\it Q2\_Q2\_Q8}\\+30\,{\it Q1\_Q2\_Q9}+340\,{\it
Q2\_Q3\_Q7}+5\,{\it Q1\_Q1\_Q10}+170\,{\it Q1\_Q4\_Q7}\\+412\,{\it Q3\_Q3\_Q6}+282\,{\it
Q4\_Q4\_Q4}+1170\,{\it Q3\_Q4\_Q5}$$
In particular we are now in a position to answer the query that prompted the post which is how many colorings there are using each of the three colors four times and the answer is
$$282$$
Here are the colorings using at most four colors:
$${\it Q12}+38\,{\it Q5\_Q7}+27\,{\it Q4\_Q8}+{\it Q1\_Q11}+5\,{\it Q2\_Q10}+13\,{\it
Q3\_Q9}+370\,{\it Q2\_Q5\_Q5}\\+698\,{\it Q3\_Q3\_Q3\_Q3}+29\,{\it Q6\_Q6}+3480\,{\it
Q1\_Q2\_Q4\_Q5}+3510\,{\it Q2\_Q2\_Q3\_Q5}\\+600\,{\it Q2\_Q4\_Q6}+2330\,{\it
Q1\_Q3\_Q3\_Q5}+2915\,{\it Q1\_Q3\_Q4\_Q4}+600\,{\it Q1\_Q1\_Q4\_Q6}\\+510\,{\it
Q1\_Q2\_Q2\_Q7}+2266\,{\it Q2\_Q2\_Q4\_Q4}+236\,{\it Q1\_Q5\_Q6}+85\,{\it Q1\_Q3\_Q8}\\+
77\,{\it Q2\_Q2\_Q8}+30\,{\it Q1\_Q2\_Q9}+2320\,{\it Q1\_Q2\_Q3\_Q6}+340\,{\it
Q1\_Q1\_Q3\_Q7}\\+13\,{\it Q1\_Q1\_Q1\_Q9}+626\,{\it Q2\_Q2\_Q2\_Q6}+340\,{\it Q2\_Q3\_Q7
}+5\,{\it Q1\_Q1\_Q10}\\+5850\,{\it Q2\_Q3\_Q3\_Q4}+135\,{\it Q1\_Q1\_Q2\_Q8}+170\,{\it
Q1\_Q4\_Q7}+412\,{\it Q3\_Q3\_Q6}\\+282\,{\it Q4\_Q4\_Q4}+370\,{\it Q1\_Q1\_Q5\_Q5}+1170
\,{\it Q3\_Q4\_Q5} $$
The code for the Fripertinger computation follows.

```
with(numtheory);
with(group):
with(combinat):

pet_disjcyc :=
proc(p)
        local dc, pos;

        dc := convert(p, 'disjcyc');

        for pos to nops(p) do
            if p[pos] = pos then
                dc := [op(dc), [pos]];
            fi;
        od;

        dc;
end;


pet_varinto_power :=
proc(N, ZA)
        local indvars, delta, v, pot, s, t, poly, k, degs,
                res, cyc;

        indvars := indets(ZA);

        res := 0;
        for delta in permute(N) do
            t := [];
            for v in indvars do
                pot := op(1, v);

                s := 0;
                for cyc in pet_disjcyc(delta) do
                    if pot mod nops(cyc) = 0 then
                        poly :=
                        mul(cat(`X`, cyc[k])^(pot/nops(cyc)),
                            k=1..nops(cyc));
                        s := s + nops(cyc)*poly;
                    fi;
                od;

                t := [op(t), v=s];
            od;

            res := res+subs(t, ZA);
        od;

        degs :=
        proc(t) local q;
            local vs, v, dl, d, sym;

            vs := indets(t);
            dl := [];

            for v in vs do
                dl := [op(dl), degree(t, v)];
            od;

            sym := [];
            for d in sort(dl) do
                if nops(sym) = 0 then
                    sym := cat(`Q`, d);
                else
                    sym := cat(sym, `_`, `Q`, d);
                fi;
            od;

            return lcoeff(t)*sym;
        end;

        if N=1 then
            return cat(`Q`, degree(res, `X1`));
        fi;

        map(degs, expand(res))/N!;
end;


cube_edge_ind :=
1/24*(a[1]^12+3*a[2]^6+6*a[4]^3+8*a[3]^4+6*a[1]^2*a[2]^5);



v :=
proc(N)
        option remember;
        local dist;

        dist := pet_varinto_power(N, cube_edge_ind);
        map(lcoeff, dist);
end;
```

Thanks go to the OP for asking such a fascinating question. Here is a link to a chain of [Polya Counting Computations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4).

**Addendum** as of **Sat Dec 21 03:20:27 CET 2013**. The above algorithm can also be used on generic graphs rather than just cubes. With two colors, we get the sequence
$$1, 2, 6, 18, 78, 522, 6178, 137352, 6002584, 509498932, 82545586656, 25251015686776,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A007869](http://oeis.org/A007869).
Three interchangeable colors produces the sequence
$$1, 3, 15, 142, 4300, 384199, 98654374, 70130880569, \\136638863494089, 730439999032117301,\ldots$$
which does not yet have an OEIS entry.
With four interchangeable colors we get
$$1, 3, 22, 513, 67685, 37205801, 74992370359, 543437207831908, 14224090440652751128,\ldots $$
The computation of the relevant cycle indices is show at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there). This [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473020/combining-symbols-with-symmetry) shows Power Group Enumeration with the flip group acting on the slots.

**Addendum Dec  13 2016.** The reader  may be interested to  know that
these generating functions can also  be computed from first principles
namely  the  Burnside  lemma  as   was  done  at  the  following  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993637/). The algorithm
is  documented  there and  in  the  linked-to  pages. I  present  this
algorithm here for reference. The output  up to sort order is the same
as from the Fripertinger computation.

```
with(combinat);

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
        local terml, d, cf, v;

        terml := [];

        cf := varp;
        for v in indets(varp) do
            d := degree(varp, v);
            terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
            cf := cf/v^d;
        od;

        [cf, terml];
end;


pet_autom2cyclesA :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, data, item, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    pos := 1; data := table();

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; item := []; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                item := [op(item), aut[cpos]];

                clen := clen+1;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
            od;

            if type(data[clen], 'list') then
                data[clen] :=
                [op(data[clen]), item];
            else
                data[clen] := [item];
            fi;
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return data;
end;


pet_flatten_automcycs :=
proc(tbl)
local res, sz, cyc;
    res := [];

    for sz in [indices(tbl, 'nolist')] do
        for cyc in tbl[sz] do
            res := [op(res), cyc];
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

cube_edge_cind :=
1/24*(a[1]^12 + 8*a[3]^4 + 6*a[4]^3 + 3*a[2]^6 + 6*a[1]^2*a[2]^5);

cube_edge_colorings :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx_colors, res, a, b,
    flat_a, flat_b, cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q,
    src, perm, acycs, gf, msetgf, term, deg, rep;

    res := 0; src := [seq(el, el=1..n)];

    for a in cube_edge_cind do
        flat_a := pet_flatten_term(a);

        perm := firstperm(n);
        while type(perm, `list`) do
            acycs := pet_autom2cyclesA(src, perm);
            flat_b := pet_flatten_automcycs(acycs);

            p := 1;
            for cyc_a in flat_a[2] do
                len_a := op(1, cyc_a);
                q := 0;

                for cyc_b in flat_b do
                    len_b := nops(cyc_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q +
                        len_b*mul(Q[el], el in cyc_b)
                        ^(len_a/len_b);
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q;
            od;

            res := res + p*flat_a[1];

            perm := nextperm(perm);
        od;
    od;

    gf := expand(res/n!);
    msetgf := 0;

    for term in gf do
        rep := 0;

        for deg in
        sort(map(Q-> degree(term, Q),
                 convert(indets(term), `list`)))
        do
            if type(rep, `integer`) then
                rep := cat(`Q`, deg);
            else
                rep := cat(rep, `_Q`, deg);
            fi;
        od;

        msetgf := msetgf + lcoeff(term)*rep;
    od;

    msetgf;
end;
```